# Why $L=\{Wa^nb^mW^R\mid\:W\in\{a,b\}^+,n>m,m>0\:\}$ is context free?

Tags: context-free

Please help me, why the following language is context free?

$L=\{Wa^nb^mW^R\mid\:W\in\{a,b\}^+,n>m,m>0\:\}$

Comment: Can you see how construct separate PDAs for $\{a^{n}b^{m}\mid n > m > 0\}$ and $\{WW^{R}\mid W\in\{a,b\}^{+}\}$? If so, how might you use nondeterminism to combine them? If this isn't the problem, where are you getting stuck? Everyone gets more out of the questions if you explain the precise problem you are having, so the answers aren't just generic exercise solutions.

Comment: You may also want to peruse [this question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/18524/how-to-prove-that-a-language-is-context-free) first.